# multiple x axis on bar chart

Tags: angular, echarts, apache-echarts, ngx-echarts

i want to add second x axis with data point as label in echarts which automatically iterates values from dataset.

I have tried by adding

```
{
            "type": "category"
        },
```

in x axis array.

link to reproduce.
[echarts option config](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeBYAULTsBEAjAhgE4DqEAJmABbYBcsArAAwA06WOA5oebcm-1mzcOlMLwDMLfgJxhQvAExSMMnLmBg5AW14AOZapwAbAKYAzMXSbTYAX1YrM2UxxPQyvVI4F4N23gaq2ADOJqYAxmAmHnRehuzYACoa-Ea8ZqmhNuy2NvY22HLARpAgnvne2GT4YPihlrAA2tlYcfFOwcAAroThJrzN3u2Yg8Px2OHFXVrQ2A5jhkkpafMLMtgAyjUQwWYQ0XMta9gAciZdYISph0NrOCcasFuQu_seR_EAuqtro3cJyVqKw-YwAjIxAv9MAAWBQAOl0ADYflDQdC4QoAJwo_6whGIkGqb6EmR_KE4ABS-AgIB6N3JmHBkKhiMRcMRAHYcXdmf9xOI4fySQJibd2mSodgACJhSgQekMpncta8u78wXiZULVnsjnC9ii_4S_7YADClHw7ggHCI1C1YIh9uGSv1qlVKtdmE-wu9YrsNkNggAHgBBIM7AYfNrtQoATxA_ToExqJg4wEIsewHwq7Wj4zA8cTOHCKbTGYV7RAwGCEEgMDoAHJ1JpgFoG07MMAzGZ6nRJFqczIAyjsLGwxHYoOOiZuCZgpG_XnFgWE7w8EQK-MCIQALL4IOkCjUKzunzbncQaCHqi8Jgd4vFdMAIUzSc3iyM-FwYU8npwwUoYAAHdeEuLoTHvBIqxrOtZiTOQymFKdxlrEwtA2AtTF_P1FnUQgyBnAAlfAyAgLp5zoY07mhSDVBov92FPMZGD_X0xlyP1kPYJcghXIt10Id8gnPfdr2PBgmMEc9LzE29JKcSYjGfV8cCE9ZP2_NJYj_EJAJAugwIgnToNrKA4NkeQkPvbBUPQzCix4mM8IIwhiNI8iFwZWB6Jw4YfK8-T4hY3yZDY4YOMMLjWmFONVyTbc1LPIg9wPcgbxPazpKvNLxLvGLFOUtdEoSDSf20kKfAA4DQMIcDaKcEzYLXBCswqqL1lsjDYyw8qTWcoiSLIiimgYrB_IZcbyUCwxgv-ML2gi1R2r4CrYv4hLMuS0ScrkzbdxknaMvyx9CBfIrrNKrSVpNKr9NgQz6pwRqzOayy2uszr7Owvr0xctyhs8ibHvYSaoWmt1WKQ7MA3QWwgA)

Comment: I dont understand what you want to achieve but if you want to use the second xAxis you need to specify the index in the series.

Comment: I want to add second x axis having bar values as labels

Comment: https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#xAxis.data ?

Comment: Is there any way to map the dataset instead of data array ( creating issue while toggling bars from legend)

Comment: Not to my knowledge.